# What to use instead DirectDraw

Tags: directx, directdraw

I've just rebuilt my old DirectDraw based game and I'm very happy with the results!
It was one of my first C++ programs in a diectx world.
But I was disappointed to discover that DirectDraw is deprecated.
After installing DirectX SDK July 2010 there is no ddraw.h and ddraw.lib.

My question: 
how to port my DirectDraw based 2D game to the recent DircetX SDK?
Is there any DirectDraw replacement?

What about OpenGL? 
Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). A tutorial can be found [here, for instance](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95054/Programming-Direct2D-Part-1).